# SwiftUI Widget: Text with DateStyle.relative - the seconds do not update in real time

Tags: swift, swiftui, widgetkit

When I create SwiftUI Widget with Text(_ : Date, style: DateStyle) using DateStyle.relative, and:

- date 1hr 1 min from now - when it goes under 1 hr, to 59 min x sec, the seconds **DO NOT** update in real time
- date 59 min from now - the seconds **DO** update in real time

Why is it so? Can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

`.relative` always show the two largest time periods, e.g.

- year and month
- month and day
- day and hour
- hour and minute
- minute and second

```
Text(Date.now + 60*60+10, style: .relative) // shows 1 hr, 0 min
Text(Date.now + 60*60, style: .relative) // shows 59 min, 59 sec
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but it seems you misread / misunderstood my question.
The problem is, when I use: `Text(Date.now + 60*60, style: .relative)` it updates this way: 59 min, 59 sec -> 59 min, 58 sec -> 59 min, 57 sec, and so on (every second), but when I use `Text(Date.now + 60*60+10, style: .relative)` it displays: 1 hr, 0 min -> 59 min, 9 sec -> 58 min, 9 sec -> 57 min, 9 sec, and so on. **The seconds do NOT update in real time**, but only once a minute **(with about a minute of delay)**. This only happens when used in Widget.

Comment: yes, I have the same behavior in Simulator, not only widget.

Comment: Is it a bug or expected behaviour?
Do you have an idea why is it so?

Comment: ok I have to correct: On simulator the `60*60+10` shows `1 hr, 0 min` for a minute, and then starts ticking down from `59 min, 59 sec` per second. If it doesn't do the same in widget, it is either a bug or an publisher update theme. Did you try to mock the behavior with a timer and/ or a time formatter string?

Comment: Timer is not allowed / not working with the widgets, that's the problem...
So time formatter won't work, because I can't update it every second on the widget. Text with DateStyle is the only thing allowed, which can be animated more frequently. And even this doesn't work properly. 
I am really disappointed so far with the widgets and WidgetKit to be honest.
So it seems I can only hope they will either fix it, or introduce more features at WWDC22.

Comment: can you use `.timer` like in the WWDC2020 EmojiRangerWidget example?

Comment: .relative style should work fine in iOS 17